# OpenCV Java Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, opencv

I am just looking for a maven dependency for OpenCV... I just found a solution someone created for version [2.4.9-4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nu.pattern/opencv/2.4.9-4) but this is to old for my usage.
Hope you can help me!
Best regards

Comment: the lib has been old. True. but what is it that you are trying to solve and why are you looking for a newer version? Please elaborate the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question

" too old for my usage"

but the solution you found is just for that version?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483802/the-java-system-library-do-not-load-opencv-library

Comment: FYI - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nu.pattern/opencv/2.4.9-7 is available. Though this was also released 4 days later to the one you are using. So not sure if that would solve what you are looking for unless you specify the details in the question.

Comment: I would suggest to search in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|opencv) and not in mvnrepository.com which is **NOT** Maven Central.

Comment: okay thanks... I will take a look at Maven Central...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall, the Java dependency only added the JNI or JNA layer that actually called the javacv code that is written in C lang. Couple of years ago, I was able to make it work with Scala and I was using the JavaCV (this uses the JNA).

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/javacv